# What is the lagrangian interaction term of a charged current weak interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, standard-model, electroweak

For example, if you have an electron coupling to a $W^{-}$ and producing an electron neutrino $e\rightarrow \nu_{e}W^{-}$. Is something like $$\frac{-g_{w}}{2\sqrt{2}}\bar{\nu}_{e}\gamma^{\mu}W^{-}_{\mu}e$$  correct? I can only find Lagrangians for electroweak interactions, not weak interactions.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction#After_electroweak_symmetry_breaking). This is in the charged current part of the EW sector. I'm not sure why you imagine it is not in it.

Comment: There is electroweak mixing in the neutral current interactions, but the charged current is all weak.

Comment: Ah thanks, just wanted to reassure myself. I was just wondering if this only applied before E-W symmetry breaking

Comment: "Before" and "after" are labels of variables/names. The current-to-gauge-field couplings are the same in gauge theory, regardless of variables' names.